# PHP Date to varchar / varchar to date

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to save a date input form field to varchar but can't figure out why it is saving a different values
Let's see some code:

HTML form field

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Vencimento</label>
<input type="text" name="due_date" value="{{ old('due_date') }}" class="date-mask form-control @error('due_date') is-invalid @enderror" placeholder="Data de vencimento:">
@error('due_date')
<small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
@enderror
</div>
```

RegisterAccountsRequest.php (using this file to validate)

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|min:3|max:255',
            'description' => 'required|min:3|max:1000',
            'value' => 'required|regex:/^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/',
            'amount_paid' => 'regex:/^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/',
            'due_date' => 'required|date_format:"d/m/Y"',
            'pay_date' => 'nullable|date_format:"d/m/Y"',
            'status' => 'required',
        ];
    }
```

FinancialController.php

```
 public function store(RegisterAccountsRequest $request){
...

$data->due_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$data->save();

...
```

The problem is that the day recorded is always today, even if I input a day in the future, like 25/10/2020

The result is (today): `2020-10-20 18:30:08`

It is a VARCHAR on the database

What am I ding wrong?

Comment: because you are calling `date` and not passing it a timestamp; so it uses "now" (`time()`) ... `date($format, $timestamp)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this `date('Y-m-d H:i:s');`  you are calling current date,  `date()` is a built in PHP function. You have `due_date` on your **request**, so get it from the request :

```
public function store(RegisterAccountsRequest $request)
{
   // ...
   $data->due_date = $request->due_date;
   $data->save();
   //...
}
```